# Is $ \forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \vdash \forall x P(x) \lor \exists xQ(x) $ provable?

Tags: logic

I know I should be able to determine whether the following holds, but I am not able to either find a model to show that this is *false* nor can I prove its correctness by using natural deduction.

> $ \forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x))  \vdash \forall x P(x) \lor \exists xQ(x) $

Could anybody help me here?

Comment: How about doing a truth tree? Altho, of course, there is no guarantee that this will give you a proof, since first-order logic is not decidable.

Comment: I think I'm supposed to show this by using natural deduction or to refute by finding a model such that this is false.

Comment: How about trying to falsify the conclusion, i.e., show invalidity by seeing if you can simultaneously make the antecedent true and the conclusion false? Your conclusion is false if $\exists x: NotP(x)$ and $\forall x NotQ(x)$; ~ is negation.

Comment: I'm afraid that I have no idea how to do that. I think my problem is, that I don't really know how I can show that for predicate logic. Wouldn't have a problem with propositional logic ..

Comment: Well, you should have some quantifier introduction and elimination rules handy if you're trying to prove this. It should be obvious you can drop the universal quantifier from the premise and introduce an existential quantifier to either side of the disjunction, or over the entire disjunction. What other quantifier introduction rules do you have?

Comment: Well of course .. $\exists$- and $ \forall $-introduction and elimination. I only can proof $ \forall x P(x) $ so far. Then I eliminate the universal quantifier but then I'm stuck with $ P(sk1) \lor Q(sk1) \implies P(sk1) $. If I try an or-elimination I am not able to show $ Q(sk1) \implies P(sk1) $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entailment is true, as you can easily check using a tableaux. To construct a natural deduction proof, I would use the deduction theorem to transform the syntactic entailment into a material conditional, then proceed to construct the conditional statement by reductio ad absurdum. I don't know which natural deduction system you're using, but a sketch of a proof would look something like this. Hopefully you can translate my proof into whatever system you're using.

$$
\begin{align}
   (1)  & \quad \forall x (P(x) \vee Q(x)) && [\text{HYP}] \\
   (2)  & \quad \neg (\forall x (P(x)) \vee \exists x (Q(x))) && [\text{HYP}] \\ 
   (3)  & \quad \neg \forall x(P(x)) \wedge \neg \exists x(Q(x)) && [\text{DM} (2)] \\
   (4)  & \quad \neg \forall x(P(x)) && [\wedge\text{-elim}(3)] \\
   (5)  & \quad \neg \exists x(Q(x)) && [\wedge\text{-elim}(3)] \\
   (6)  & \quad \exists x (\neg P(x)) && [\neg\forall\text{-elim}(4)] \\
   (7)  & \quad \forall x (\neg Q(x)) && [\neg\exists\text{-elim}(5)] \\
   (8)  & \quad \neg P(a) && [\exists\text{-elim}(6)] \\
   (9)  & \quad \neg Q(a) && [\forall\text{-elim}(7)] \\
   (10) & \quad \neg P(a) \wedge \neg Q(a) && [\wedge\text{-intro}(8,9)] \\
   (11) & \quad P(a) \vee Q(a) && [\forall\text{-elim}(1)] \\
   (12) & \quad \neg (\neg P(a) \wedge \neg Q(a)) && [\text{DM}(11)] \\
   (13) & \quad \forall x(P(x) \vee \exists x(Q(x)) && [\text{RAA}(2,10,12)] \\
   (14) & \quad \forall x (P(x) \vee Q(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x(P(x) \vee \exists x(Q(x)) && [\rightarrow\text{-intro}(1,13)]
\end{align}
$$

Since you don't have De Morgan's Laws, I will sketch a proof that $\neg (P \wedge Q)$ implies $\neg P \vee \neg Q$ using the primitive rules of natural deduction, leaving the proof that $\neg (P \vee Q)$ implies $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$ as an exercise. The proofs are similar, so hopefully the following will be useful.

$$
\begin{align}
 (1) & \quad \neg (P \wedge Q) && [\text{HYP}] \\
 (2) & \quad \neg (\neg P \vee \neg Q) && [\text{HYP}] \\
 (3) & \quad \neg P && [\text{HYP}] \\
 (4) & \quad \neg P \vee \neg Q && [\vee\text{-intro}(3)] \\
 (5) & \quad P && [\text{RAA}(3,4)] \\
 (6) & \quad \neg Q && [\text{HYP}] \\
 (7) & \quad \neg P \vee \neg Q && [\vee\text{-intro}(6)] \\
 (8) & \quad Q && [\text{RAA}(3,7)] \\
 (9) & \quad P \wedge Q && [\wedge\text{-intro}(5,8)] \\
 (10) & \quad \neg P \vee \neg Q && [\text{RAA}(1,9)] \\
 (11) & \quad \neg (P \wedge Q) \rightarrow \neg P \vee \neg Q && [\rightarrow\text{-intro}(1,10)]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Well yes I think I get that but the problem here is with $(14)$ since this would just be a claim that also needed to be proved first or is this truly valid?

Comment: The rule for conditional introduction states that if $Q$ is provable under assumption $P$, then $P \rightarrow Q$ is provable. The rule for reductio ad absurdum states that if $Q$ and $\neg Q$ is provable under assumption $P$, then $\neg P$ is provable. The proof works by first assuming (1) for conditional introduction, then assuming (2) for reductio ad absurdum. In line (13), we derive the negation of (2) and discharge (2). In line (14), we derive the desired conditional from (1) and (13) and discharge (1).

Comment: Hm.. I get your proof, but you're using rules I've never seen before and I am quite sure that I'm not allowed to use e.g. that rule you are using in $(3)$. I'd first have to prove this before I am able to proceed here ..

Comment: The rule used in (3) is known as De Morgan's Law, which state that $\neg (P \vee Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$. It is used again in (12), after translating $P \vee Q$ into $\neg \neg P \vee \neg \neg Q$. You should be ale to prove De Morgan's Law without much trouble, or just look up a proof online.

Comment: I know that what you answered is right but it seems I have a problem proving this using my tool here .. it is called **pandora**. This all makes sense to me and I'd do this the same way but it seems that this tool won't let me to solve it like this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tool, but I'm confident that you should be able to translate my proof into an arbitrary natural deduction system - assuming you're working in classical first-order logic. Next time, I would suggest noting the system you're working in, or if you don't know its name, at least the rules you're permitted to use. Then people can provide proofs using those rules.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the antecedent is true and the conclusion is false.  If the conclusion is false, then $\forall{x}P(x)$ and $\exists{x}Q(x)$ are both false.  If $\forall{x}P(x)$ is false, then $P(x_0)$ is false for some $x_0$.  We know that $P(x_0)\vee Q(x_0)$ (from the antecedent).  Since $P(x_0)$ is false, $Q(x_0)$ must be true.  Therefore $\exists{x}Q(x)$ is true.  This contradicts our assumption that the conclusion was false.  Therefore the conclusion is true.