# Intuitionistic proof of $\forall x(P(x)\lor Q(x))\to(\forall x P(x)\lor\exists x Q(x))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, constructive-mathematics

Similar to [Is $ \forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \vdash \forall x P(x) \lor \exists xQ(x) $ provable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567505/is-forall-xpx-lor-qx-vdash-forall-x-px-lor-exists-xqx-provab), but with intuitionistic logic. I expect it is not, since I don't think the $\exists x Q(x)$ on the right is very "constructive", but curiously the finite version of this

$$((p_1\lor q_1)\land(p_2\lor q_2))\to((p_1\land p_2)\lor(q_1\lor q_2))$$

*is* intutitionistically provable, since you can break up the left side into four cases and verify that each satisfies the right side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not intuitionistically valid. Here is a [Kripke model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_intuitionistic_logic) where it doesn't hold:

There are two frames, $w$ and $u$ with $w<u$.

In $w$ the universe is $\{\mathtt a\}$ and $P(\mathtt a)$ is true.

In $u$ the universe is $\{\mathtt a,\mathtt b\}$, and $P(\mathtt a)$ and $Q(\mathtt b)$ are true.

Then both frames satisfy $\forall x(P(x)\lor Q(x))$.

However $w$ doesn't satisfy $\forall x\,P(x) \lor \exists x\,Q(x)$. The first disjunct is false because the intuitionistic interpretation of $\forall$ must be true in all reachable frames (and it clearly isn't true in $u$), and the second is clearly false in $w$.

Comment: Very nice. I really need to get the hang of Kripke frames for this sort of thing; the Heyting open-set model is harder to work with since it is infinite so I never no if my counterexample is general enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, here's an answer using the open set model. What we have to do is find families of open sets $P_i$ and $Q_i$ in some topological space $X$ such that:
$$
Int(\bigcap_i(P_i \cup Q_i)) \not\subseteq Int(\bigcap_i P_i) \cup (\bigcup_i Q_i) \tag*{(*)}
$$
To do this, take $X$ to be the unit interval $[0, 1]$ and for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$ define
$$
P_i = [0, \frac{1}{i}) \\
Q_i = (\frac{1}{i+1}, 1]
$$
Since $X = P_i \cup Q_i$ for any $i$, the left-hand side of $\mbox{(*)}$ is equal to $X$. However, $\bigcap_i P_i = \{0\}$, which has empty interior, so the right-hand side of (*) is $\bigcup_i Q_i = (0, 1] \not \supseteq X$.

Comment: Can you point to a description of how open-set models for intuitionistic _predicate_ logic work? I tried looking, but my usual sources seem to cover only the propositional case.

Comment: I know of it from folklore and have seen it discussed and used in works of Scedrov, van Dalen and others. Here is one http://aleteya.cs.buap.mx/~jlavalle/papers/van%20Dalen/Intuitionistic%20Logic.pdf